# equivalent of windows+L in osx snow leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac)

whenever i used to leave my system i just press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in my windows system. Now i have macbook pro with snow leopard OS and i am searching for equivalent of windows+l.

So my question is what is the keyboard shortcut to lock macbook pro?

i know the shortcut <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
But this shortcut is for logout not to lock the system.

Comment: This question has been answered over at Superuser SE. [Fast User Switching/Apple Menu](http://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu/)

Comment: @sorens: thanks good to know. Actually I like more my option as it also sends to sleep my screen and does not require much configuration. Depends if Vivart wants exactly the same as WINDOWS+L or just wants to lock the Mac before going away (as I do)

Comment: <kbd> does not work in comments, unfortunately.

Comment: I'd leave this as not a duplicate, personally. I didn't know windows + L was a keyboard shortcut to lock the computer. Yes - it's the same answer, but the search terms to get to it seem quite different to me...

Comment: @bmike there's also the "windows+L" keyword in the other question.

Comment: So there is - I stand corrected and convinced :-) Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd> sets the display to sleep. If you have then the option "Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins" set in "Security & Privacy" it will lock your machine.

This will only put the display to sleep not the system: not exactly what you asked but the additional screen sleep is not bad (less energy consumption :-)

There are other answers here that point out ways to establish a automation to lock the screen from a keyboard command of your choosing. See

- [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac)
- [Lock screen with LaunchBar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25487/lock-screen-with-launchbar)
- https://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu

The last two show several methods to script this. You can then use [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/launchbar/) or [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) or another tool to launch the action you prefer.

Comment: I think you meant control, not command.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a "lock" feature in Mac OS X. Your best option is to enable the "Require password after sleep or screen saver begins" option in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General. Then, either put the screen or entire computer to sleep. To put just the screen to sleep from the keyboard, type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>. This will make the screen go blank, but your computer will still be running. To put the entire computer to sleep, type <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>. This will cause all running processes to stop until the computer is woken up.